# Django model with dynamic fields based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to implement a model where only a subset of the fields should be presented in forms, based on a foreign key in the model.
The total number of fields is relatively low (~20), but may change frequently with different values of the foreign key.
I would like to use something like single table inheritance, but with a single model (no inheritance). I looked at existing packages eav, dynamic models... but they did not seem to fit my needs.
I part of the requirement is that I would like to query the models by sql without too many joins.

Here is a use case representing applications to grants based on a request for application (rfa). The rfa is entered in the admin by staff and the applications are made by end users.

```
application class
    rfa (request for application): foreign key
    field_1
    ...
    field_20
rfa class:
    app_fields (coma separated list of field names)
```

In the forms, only the fields in app_fields should be visible for a particular rfa.

I have the rfa part covered with [django-separatedvaluesfield](https://github.com/ulule/django-separatedvaluesfield) and I was wondering how to implement the application pages so that they work with generic views in the frontend and admin, and be DRY.

For the update views,  I could have a method in the application model, but it would not work for create as the rfa is not defined for create:

```
def get_current_app_fields(self):
    return self.rfp.app_fields
```

Any ideas on the best DRY strategy to implement frontend views and admin?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I get it correctly, but maybe dynamically loading the app's model fields with the "apps" application (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/) could be a good point to start off. You could use a form factory that takes a list of fields based on the ForeignKey. You could then pass the custom form to the template and render it there dynamically. Alternatively you could also send it as rendered HTML via AJAX.

Comment: Sorry the name Application may be confusing, here it is just a model class, nothing to do with Django applications.

Comment: I know, but Django's "application" app allows you to dynamically load and read registered models (see reference above). So you should be able to store the config in a Database and load it afterwards. Have a look here for modelform factory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory

I did something similar some time ago. I only had one Database Model and rendered the forms dynamically based on some parameters. Saving these parameters should be quite easy.